# MultipartUpload error

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I'm working with the [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) and the [AWS SDK for PHP](http://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/).

I'm trying to use MultiPartUpload to upload my files but I have this error:

> PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 2 passed to
>   Guzzle\Service\Client::getCommand() must be of the type array,
>   string given, called in /var/www/html/aws/Guzzle/Service/Client.php on
>   line 76 and defined in /var/www/html/aws/Guzzle/Service/Client.php on
>   line 79

This error occurs when I put more than 10 simultaneous uploads.

Anyone knows why?

**PHP:** (`connection.php`)

```
use Aws\Common\Exception\MultipartUploadException;
use Aws\S3\Model\MultipartUpload\UploadBuilder;
use Aws\S3\S3Client;

$uploaded = (object) $_FILES['uploaded_file'];


$this->file  = $uploaded->tmp_name;

$arrayConfig =  array(
            'key'    => $this->accessKey,
            'secret' => $this->secretKey
        );

$this->awsClient = S3Client::factory($arrayConfig);

$uploader = UploadBuilder::newInstance()
            ->setClient($this->awsClient)
            ->setSource($this->file)
            ->setBucket($this->bucket)
            ->setKey($this->file_name_id)
            ->build();
```

I have a crontab service with 10 commands at same time:

```
*/05 * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/user/upload_test.php
*/05 * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/user/upload_test.php
*/05 * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/user/upload_test.php
*/05 * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/user/upload_test.php
*/05 * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/user/upload_test.php
*/05 * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/user/upload_test.php
*/05 * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/user/upload_test.php
*/05 * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/user/upload_test.php
*/05 * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/user/upload_test.php
*/05 * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/user/upload_test.php
```

upload_test.php:

```
$local_file = '/home/user/file.zip';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;)" );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/connection.php' );

$post_array = array(
    "uploaded_file" => "@" . $local_file,
    "function" => "upload"
);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_array );
$response = curl_exec( $ch );
```

Comment: What do you mean by "This error occurs when I put more than 10 simultaneous uploads"? This code sample does not reflect this.

Comment: Does this happen every time you run the offending code or is it intermittent?

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean by "10 simultaneous uploads". There is nothing in the code you posted that shows how you are doing these simultaneous uploads. I can't reproduce this issue, so I'm wondering if you can get anymore of a stack trace. The error message you posted tells us what went wrong, but not part of the code triggered that. Doing multipart uploads creates many commands.

Comment: Ah, you have a cron, OK. I still need you to get more information from the stack trace for that error. The error mentions that something is passing in a string instead of an array. I looked through the multipart upload code, and that really doesn't make sense. If you could get more of the stack trace so we can pinpoint where that call is happening, then it would help us figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: Another question. Does the error happen if you reduce the number concurrent uploads. For example, if only do 5 at a time, do you run into that error?

Comment: If I have 20 at time 7/8 give me that error. If I have 5 at time I have no errors.

Comment: @JeremyLindblom I don't have more errors in stack trace.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65391/discussion-between-jeremy-lindblom-and-jorge-b).

Comment: @JeremyLindblom you don't know why I have this issue?

Comment: Not so far at least. I've never seen anyone report an issue like this where a code path, that is known to work, triggers fatal errors, but only intermittently. Whatever, is going on here, I highly doubt that it is an issue with the SDK, and I have to believe it is something to do with your system. If it works with 5 at a time, then do 5 at a time, not 10. It seems like it _could_ be due to a lack of resources (file descriptors? memory?). If it is the code, then you need to narrow down and determine exact reproducible conditions that trigger this error. I can't reproduce this on my system.

Comment: Have you tried using [setMinPartSize](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.S3.Model.MultipartUpload.UploadBuilder.html#_setMinPartSize) to something higher like 25MB? The default is 5MB chunks. I asked you this in the chat, but SO seems to have deleted our chat. :-/ Tis should reduce the amount of concurrent HTTP requests your cronjobs are creating and may make a difference in how many you can do at a time if the problem is indeed related to system resources.

Comment: I'm testing with 5 uploads for 5 days and 4/5 times a day an upload fails. I have tryed with 25MB and 250MB and I have same problem. 
I have no problems with memory, I think.

Comment: I will try to specify better the issue.